# ∃-queries and ∀-queries with Z3 fixedpoint engine

Tags: z3, smt

I'm confused and struggling to understand how two different input formats for Z3 fixedpoint engine are related. Short example: suppose I want to prove the existance of negative numbers. I declare a function that returns 1 for non-negative numbers and 0 for negative and then asking solver to fail if there are arguments for which function returns 0. But there is one restriction: I want solver to respond `sat` when there exists at least one negative number and `unsat` if all numbers are non-negative.

It is trivially with using `declare-rel` and `query` format:

```
(declare-rel f (Int Int))
(declare-rel fail ())
(declare-var n Int)
(declare-var m Int)

(rule (=> (< n 0) (f n 0)))
(rule (=> (>= n 0) (f n 1)))

(rule (=> (and (f n m) (= m 0)) fail))
(query fail)
```

But it becomes tricky while using pure SMT-LIB2 format (with `forall`). For example, straightforward

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Bool)
(declare-fun fail () Bool)

(assert (forall ((n Int)) 
    (=> (< n 0) (f n 0))))
(assert (forall ((n Int)) 
    (=> (>= n 0) (f n 1))))

(assert (forall ((n Int) (m Int)) 
    (=> (and (f n m) (= m 0)) fail)))
(assert (not fail))

(check-sat)
```

returns `unsat`. Unsurprisingly, changing `(= m 0)` to `(= m 1)` results the same. We can get `sat` only implying `fail` from `(= m 2)`. The problem is that I can't understand, *how to ask solver* using this format.

How I'm understanding it at the moment, while using `forall`-form we can ask to find only ∀-solutions, i.e. the answer `sat` means that solver managed to find interpretation (or invariant) satisfiying all assertions for **all** values, and `unsat` means that there are no such functions. In other words, it tries to *prove*, putting the 'proof' (the invariant) into the model (obviously, when `sat`).

On the contrary, when `query`ing the solution in the `declare-rel` format solver searches the solution for **some** variables, just like the constraints are under the ∃-quantifier. In other words, it gives the *counter-example*. It can only print the invariant in case of `unsat`.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I understanding it correct? I feel like I miss some key ideas. For example, a general idea of how to express `(query ...)` in terms of `(assert (forall ...))` will be really helpfull (and will answer question 2 automaticly).
2. Is there a way to solve such ∃-constraints (outputting `sat` when counterexample was found) with pure SMT-LIB2 format? If yes then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the format that uses "declare-rel", "declare-var", "rule" and "query" is a custom extension to SMT-LIB2. The "declare-var" feature is convenient for omitting bound variables from multiple rules. It also allows formulating Datalog rules with stratified negation and the semantics of this is what you should expect from stratified negation. By convention it uses "sat" to indicate that a query has a derivation, and "unsat" that no derivation exists for a query.

It turns out that standard SMT-LIB2 can express pretty much what you want for 
Horn clauses without negation. Rules become implications and queries are implications of the form: (=> query false), or as you wrote it (not query).
A derivation in the custom format corresponds to a proof of the empty clause (e.g., proof of "query", which then proves "false"). So existence of a derivation means that the SMT-LIB2 assertions are "unsat". Conversely, if there is an interpretation (a model) for the Horn clauses, then such a model establishes that there is no derivation. The clauses are "sat".

In other words:

```
 "sat" for datalog extension   <=> "unsat" for SMT-LIB2 formulation
 "unsat" for datalog extension <=> "sat" for SMT-LIB2 formulation
```

The advantage of using the pure SMT-LIB2 format, when it applies, is that
there are no special syntax extensions. These are plain SMT formulas and
others who wish to solve this class of formulas don't have to write special
extensions, they just have to ensure that the solvers that are tuned to
Horn clauses recognize the appropriate class of formulas. (Z3's implementation
of the HORN fragment does allow some flexibility in writing down Horn clauses.
You can have disjunctions in the bodies and you can have Curried implications).

There is one drawback with using the SMT-LIB2 format that the rule-based format helps with: when there is a derivation of the query, then the rule-based format has pragmas for printing elements of a tuple. Note that in general the query relation can take arguments. This feature is useful for finite domain relations.
Your example above uses integers, so the relations are not finite domain, but examples in the online-tutorial contain finite domain instances.
Now a derivation of a query also corresponds to a resolution proof. You can extract a resolution proof from the SMT-LIB2 case, but I have to say it is rather
convoluted and I have not found a way to use it effectively. The "duality" engine for Horn clauses generates derivations in a more accessible format than
the default proof format of Z3. Either way, it is likely that users run into obstacles if they try to work with the proof certificates because they are rarely used. The rule-based format does have another feature that assembles a set of predicates with instances that correspond to a derivation trail. It is easier to eyeball this output.

Comment: Nikolaj, thank you very much for a clear and complete answer.